# Error dynamic binding sap.m.list BindAggregation

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm new with sapui5 and I'm trying to binding sap.m.list dynamically but there is no data displayed in the list and I didn't solve this problem

there is my code:

```
_bindfilter: function(Filter) {

        var oList = this.getView().byId("list");
        var array = [];
    
        
        array.push(Filter);
        var Filter2 = {"metadata" : array } ; 
        oList.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(array));


       var oTemplate = new sap.m.InputListItem({
                label: "{NameF0}",
                 content: [ new sap.m.Button("but4", {text:"Button4"})]


        });
        oList.bindAggregation("items","/array", oTemplate); 

         
    oList.setBusy(false);
    debugger;
    },
```

I passed into the method a parameter which I want it to be displayed in the list

this picture shows the parameter with data in the debugger

[image]

I'm really stuck and I need your help please feel free to help me.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sap.m.Table` instead of `sap.m.List`. Good explanation about binding is [here](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070).